# I want a kid on Skyrim Elder Scrolls V

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On Skyrim, if I marry the girl that owns the veggie stand in White Run, then will her kid become mine and I give it stuff? Like as if I adopted it from the orphanage?

Answer (score 3):

That particular NPC is not marriagable, which probably applies to any NPC with a kid, but the answer to your question may be on [this page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Carlotta_Valentia), which states that even if she is made marriagable through the console and married, her kid stays behind in Whiterun (look under bugs).

Answer (score 0):

Who you're trying to marry in marriable even if you complete her quest.

get the Hearthfire DLC which allows you to adopt children or get the **Child Adoption** mod.

There are 5 places with each child to adopt and requirements:

Riften: Honorhall Orphanage: Runa Fair Shield, Hroar, Samuel, Francios Beautfort. Requirement: Complete Innocnce Lost from Aventus Arentino in Windhelm in the Arentino Residence.

Whiterun: Gildergreen tree: Lucia. Rquirement: Ask her why she's begging.

Windhelm: Near gate to docks: Sophie. Requirement: Ask her about her parents.

Dawnstar: Around Quicksilver Mine: Alesan Requirement: Ask him about why he's in Dawnstar.

Solitude: Katla's Farm: Blaise. Requirement: Ask him about how farming is going.

Answer (score -1):

This is only possible if you get the Hearthfire DLC that lets you adopt kids and build your own house. The house will cost lots of gold but the kid is free

Comment: He's asking for ways to get children in vanilla, not DLCs.

Answer (score -1):

To get a kid you must have the expansion pack Hearth Fire which you can download

That kid that you were talking about is now considered yours but she won't treat you any differently and you can't give her commands